# How to make few PUT actions in the same controller with different arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the next code:

```
public class TodoController : ApiController
{
    //...

    public void Put([FromBody] Todo todo)
    {
        //Some update operation for singe todo
    }

    public void Put([FromBody] IEnumerable<Todo> todo)
    {
        //Some update operation for few todo
    }

}

public class Todo
{

    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Title { get; set; }

    public Boolean Completed { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make few PUT operations:
1) Updates the single entry
2) Updates the Array of entries at once

But when I'm making the the HttpPut request to API to `TodoController` its shows me the message:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nVoid Put(Todo) on type TodoController\r\nVoid Put(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Todo]) on type TodoController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"...
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thx a lot for any advance.

Comment: Rest doesn't support overloads, implement a single JObject and detect whats comming instead

Comment: try using custom names for metods ad their parameters defining in `WebApiConfig`

Comment: `Eric Herlitz` can you please provide some advance with example of your idea?

Comment: Create two controllers.  A single todo and a set of todos are completely different resources.  You controllers should be extremely lightweight anyway.  Creating two shouldn't be so painful.

Comment: @EricHerlitz REST is an architectural style, and applies no constraints on implementation mechanisms.  Your statement `REST doesn't support overloads` does not make any sense.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I have to agree a bit, let me put it this way. There is no built-in way to resolve overloaded methods when using any default implementation of REST in .net, this goes for SOAP as well.

Comment: @EricHerlitz Web API will select overloaded actions by matching query parameters to action parameters.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Not OOTB, in that case you will have to implement Attribute Routing or modify the default routing

Comment: @EricHerlitz  I just tried it to confirm.  Web API OOTB with regular routing, the action selector will select between overloads using query parameters.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Could you put those sources somewhere or form an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you are going to have to define separate routes for each method. A good way to manage this would be to utilise the [Attribute routing](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/) nuget package for this. It makes setting up your routing a lot easier and even comes as part of WebApi 2. The documentation for it can be found [here](http://attributerouting.net/).

Here's an example:

```
//define first route
[PUT("PutMethod1")]
public void Put([FromBody] Todo todo)
{
    //Some update operation for singe todo
}

//define second route
[PUT("PutMethod2")]
public void Put([FromBody] IEnumerable<Todo> todo)
{
    //Some update operation for few todo
}
```